# Code for a Person DTO, with tests

Tags: php, php5, dto

My needs are to manage DTO in a php5.3 application. I've written few lines of code in TDD with phpunit 6. The scenario I want to implement is a request with following fields:

- name
- surname
- password
- alias
- email
- address
- civic_number
- country

And I need to create DTO's with

- credentials
- info
- address

### Provide DTO properties

Each DTO should provide its own properties.

```
public function testProvideDtoPropertyNames()
{
    $propertyNames = Person::getPropertyNames();

    $expectedProperties = array(
        'name',
        'surname',
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        $expectedProperties,
        $propertyNames
    );
}
```

### Getters

I also want that all properties are available via getters:

```
public function testProvidePropertyViaGeneralGetter()
{
    $dto = Person::createFromArray(array(
        'name' => 'Simone',
    ));

    $this->assertEquals(
        'Simone',
        $dto->get('name')
    );
}
```

### Filtering

The main purpose here is to filter all fields and just keep consideration of the DTO's properties:

```
public function testDTOAcceptOnlyItsOwnProperties()
{
    $dto = Person::createFromArray(array(
        'name' => 'Simone',
        'sfadfsa' => 'Simone',
    ));

    $expectedProperties = array(
        'name' => 'Simone',
        'surname' => null,
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        $expectedProperties,
        $dto->asArray()
    );
}
```

### Serialization

Serializing and un serializing I want that my code works fine and without side effect.

```
public function testSerializationKeepSameProperties()
{
    $dto = Person::createFromArray(array(
        'name' => 'Simone',
        'surname' => 'Gentili',
        'sadfasdrname' => 'Gentili',
    ));

    $serialized = serialize($dto);
    $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);

    $this->assertEquals(
        $dto->asArray(),
        $unserialized->asArray()
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        array(
            'name' => 'Simone',
            'surname' => 'Gentili',
        ),
        $unserialized->asArray()
    );
}
```

Are those tests good? I hope yes but any suggestions are welcome.

Finally, ... the code:

A DTO can be easily done with a simple class with public properties:

```
class Person extends Dto
{
    public $name;
    public $surname;
}
```

Here the production code:

```
abstract class Dto
{
    private $properties;

    private function __construct(array $properties)
    {
        $this->properties = $properties;
    }

    public static function createFromArray($properties)
    {
        return new static($properties);
    }

    public function set($propertyName, $propertyValue)
    {
        $this->$propertyName = $propertyValue;
    }

    public function get($propertyName)
    {
        return isset($this->properties[$propertyName])
            ? $this->properties[$propertyName]
            : null;
    }

    public static function getPropertyNames()
    {
        $reflected = new ReflectionClass(new static(array()));

        $properties = $reflected->getProperties(
            ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC
        );

        return array_map(function ($item) {
            return $item->getName();
        }, $properties);
    }

    public function asArray()
    {
        $properties = array();

        foreach (static::getPropertyNames() as $itemValue) {
            $properties[$itemValue] = $this->get($itemValue);
        }

        return $properties;
    }

    public function __sleep()
    {
        foreach (self::getPropertyNames() as $propertyName) {
            $this->set(
                $propertyName,
                $this->get($propertyName)
            );
        }

        return self::getPropertyNames();
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        foreach (self::getPropertyNames() as $propertyName) {
            $this->properties[$propertyName] = $this->$propertyName;
            $this->$propertyName = null;
        }

        return self::getPropertyNames();
    }
}
```

Comment: you do know php5.3 is kind of no longer supported? It stopped getting security updates in 2014! http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Yes I know. ...

Comment: It's no longer supported by the PHP team, but Red Hat should still be somewhat supporting 5.3 with some security updates as part of the RHEL 6 operating system for another three years.

Answer (score 2):

In the tests (and anywhere else), you should use constants to ensure correct spelling of the properties :

```
const PERSON_NAME = 'name';
const PERSON_SURNAME = 'surname';
...
$expectedProperties = array(self::PERSON_NAME,self::PERSON_SURNAME);
```

Then the Filtering and Serialization tests are very similar while they should be atomic (one test tests one thing) : you should not test Filtering whike testing Serialization.

In the production code there is one error : you set the desired property (i.e. `$this->name`) while you get the internal array's key (`$this->properties['name']`). To keep the simplicity of defining an object as a class with public properties you should drop the internal array. This will also make the `__sleep` and `__wakeup` calls much clearer.

Also a design flaw is to use the [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) : it seems unavoidable but depending on your usage there might be performance issues. Using a caching system such as a static array will help. In particular if you look at the `__wakeup` and `__sleep` function you will notice a repeted call to the `getPropertyNames` method.

Finally what might be problematic is that you don't check if the property exists when setting or getting. If it does not you should throw an exception. There are [magic methods in PHP5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) (`__get`, `__set` and `__call`) ; you may do better using them. This way you will be able to use `$personName = $person->getName()` / `$person->setName('Simone')` as well as `$personName = $person->name` / `$person->name = 'Simone'`

Tests :

```
const PERSON_NAME = 'name';
const PERSON_SURNAME = 'surname';

public function testProvideDtoPropertyNames()
{
    $propertyNames = Person::getPropertyNames();

    $expectedProperties = array(
        self::PERSON_NAME,
        self::PERSON_SURNAME,
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        $expectedProperties,
        $propertyNames
    );
}
public function testProvidePropertyViaGeneralGetter()
{
    $dto = Person::createFromArray(array(
        self::PERSON_NAME => 'Simone',
    ));

    $this->assertEquals(
        'Simone',
        $dto->getName()
    );
}
public function testDTOAcceptOnlyItsOwnProperties()
{
    $dto = Person::createFromArray(array(
        self::PERSON_NAME => 'Simone',
        'non existent property' => 'Simone',
    ));

    $expectedProperties = array(
        self::PERSON_NAME => 'Simone',
        self::PERSON_SURNAME => null,
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        $expectedProperties,
        $dto->asArray()
    );
}
public function testSerializationKeepSameProperties()
{
    $properties = array(
        self::PERSON_NAME => 'Simone',
        self::PERSON_SURNAME => null,
    );

    $dto = Person::createFromArray($properties);

    $serialized = serialize($dto);
    $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);

    $this->assertEquals(
        $dto->asArray(),
        $unserialized->asArray()
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        $properties,
        $unserialized->asArray()
    );
}
```

Production code :

```
class DtoException extends Exception
{
}
abstract class Dto
{
    private static $propertyNamesByClass = array();

    private function __construct(array $properties)
    {
        foreach($properties as $propertyName=>$propertyValue)
            if(Static::hasPropertyName($propertyName))
                $this->set($propertyName,$propertyValue);
    }
    public function __call($method, array $arguments)
    {
        $getOrSet = substr($method, 0, 3);
        if($getOrSet != 'get' && $getOrSet != 'set')
            throw new DtoException('"'.get_class($this).'" has no method "'.$method.'"');

        $propertyName = strtolower(substr($method, 3));
        if(!Static::hasPropertyName($propertyName))
            throw new DtoException('"'.get_class($this).'" has no property "'.$propertyName.'"');

        $getOrSetMethod = array($this,$getOrSet);
        array_unshift($arguments,$propertyName);
        return call_user_func_array($getOrSetMethod, $arguments);
    }
    public function __get($propertyName)
    {
        if(!Static::hasPropertyName($propertyName))
            throw new DtoException('"'.get_class($this).'" has no property "'.$propertyName.'"');

        return $this->get($propertyName);
    }
    public function __set($propertyName, $propertyValue)
    {
        if(!Static::hasPropertyName($propertyName))
            throw new DtoException('"'.get_class($this).'" has no property "'.$propertyName.'"');

        return $this->set($propertyName, $propertyValue);
    }

    public static function createFromArray($properties)
    {
        return new Static($properties);
    }

    public function set($propertyName, $propertyValue)
    {
        $this->$propertyName = $propertyValue;
    }

    public function get($propertyName)
    {
        return $this->$propertyName;
    }

    public static function getPropertyNames()
    {
        $className = get_called_class();
        if(isset(self::$propertyNamesByClass[$className]))
            return self::$propertyNamesByClass[$className];

        $reflected = new ReflectionClass($className);
        $reflectedProperties = $reflected->getProperties(
            ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC
        );

        $propertyNames = array();
        foreach($reflectedProperties as $reflectedProperty) {
            $propertyNames[] = $reflectedProperty->getName();
        }

        self::$propertyNamesByClass[$className] = $propertyNames;
        return $propertyNames;
    }
    public static function hasPropertyName($propertyName)
    {
        $propertyNames = Static::getPropertyNames();
        return in_array($propertyName,$propertyNames);
    }

    public function asArray()
    {
        $values = array();

        foreach (Static::getPropertyNames() as $propertyName) {
            $values[$propertyName] = $this->get($propertyName);
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function __sleep()
    {
        $propertyNames = self::getPropertyNames();

        foreach ($propertyNames as $propertyName) {
            $propertyValue = $this->get($propertyName);
            $this->set($propertyName, $propertyValue);
        }

        return $propertyNames;
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        $propertyNames = self::getPropertyNames();

        return $propertyNames;
    }
}
```

I tested it on PHP5.3 and [it works](https://3v4l.org/rL8Uf), however I have to tell you that it does not work on PHP5.2- or PHP7+.